# installed watchdog module .but i am not access the module

Tags: python, python-watchdog

while i am using "import watchdog" in python...its showing no module named watchdog....im working in linux (centos)

directory of watchdog module-----'/home/admin/watchdog'

i have tried all the following code

1)

```
import os
import sys
env=os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars('/home/admin/watchdog/src/watchdog/event'))
sys.path.insert(0, env)
import home.admin.watchdog.src.watchdog.event
```

2)

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/admin/watchdog/src/watchdog/event/')
```

3)

```
from home.admin.watchdog.observers import Observer
from home.admin.watchdog.src.watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
```

4)

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/admin/watchdog/src/watchdog/event/"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: installed watchdog module but not able to access the module

Comment: Make sure the file/module you are working in isn't called watchdog! Also depending on your version of python make sure you use or try pip or pip3

Comment: how are you installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Use PyCharm to write code in python
It helps to solve module errors by itself
It will show hint button when there is an error. So if we press that it will show how to fix or fix it by itsown

Answer (score 0):

You should install watchdog using `pip` (or `pip3`) with `pip install watchdog` (or `pip3 install watchdog`). This way `pip` will take care of everything and then you can import it with `import watchdog`.

Since you have the source you can also go to the base directory and execute `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py install` which will both install it such that you can import watchdog with `import watchdog`.

Finally the proper directory you should include in `PYTHONPATH` should actually be `/home/admin/watchdog/src/`.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/admin/watchdog/src/')

import watchdog.event
```