# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'

Tags: python

I just installed watchdog in the command prompt using pip install watchdog.I uninstalled and reinstalled using python pip -m install watchdog. Neither of these is getting watchdog to work as I keep getting this error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'

not sure if me using sublime text 3 is what is affecting this. 
Please help
Here is my code:

```
from watchdog.observers import observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEvenHandler

import os
import json
import time
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed on your computer? What exact commands are you using to execute the script?

Comment: I installed the most recent python and then installed Anaconda3. I think this means I have two versions of python. I uninstalled python 2 a while back, when i type "where python" I only get two resutls: C:\Users\caleb\python and C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe. Not sure what you mean by exact commands.

Comment: Sorry after checking again I have a python 3.7.6 and a python 3.8.2. Import watchdog works for 3.7.6 but not 3.8.2. It is not working in sublime text. Is there a way for me to download it specifically for 3.8.2?

Comment: `python` usually refers to python 2.  Try `python3 -m pip ...`

Answer (score 3):

This is a [duplicate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55160434/installed-watchdog-module-but-i-am-not-access-the-module).
In summary, 
1. It may be a python version inconsistency:
 * If you use python command, execute this command:

```
python -m pip install watchdog
```

- If you use python3 command, execute this command:

```
python3 -m pip install watchdog
```

- If all didn't solved problem, reinstall module.

```
python -m pip install watchdog
python -m pip uninstall watchdog
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install watchdog
python3 -m pip uninstall watchdog
```

installing module with `python -m pip install` is preferred to `pip install`.

Comment: I did both downloads and then made a new build system in sublime text 3 using python 3.7 as it installed their first. Howevr I now have a new error with the same text from above. Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'observer' from 'watchdog.observers' (C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\watchdog\observers\__init__.py)