# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-3.9, watchdog

I have pip3 installed watchdog into my python3 venv.

**which pip3 shows: /Users/user/qwerty/project/bin/pip3**

**which pythons hows : /Users/user/qwerty/project/bin/python**

When i enter the Python interpreter and 'import watchdog' it works fine. However as soon as i run a nose2 Test it fails to import watchdog:

(project) Users-MacBook-Pro:project user$ python3
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:23:42)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> import watchdog

The error i am getting is:

> ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_myscript
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose2/plugins/loader/discovery.py", line 201, in _find_tests_in_file
> module = util.module_from_name(module_name)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose2/util.py", line 77, in module_from_name
> **import**(name)
> File "/Users/user/qwerty/project/project/tests/myscript.py", line 5, in 
> from whippetwatcher import WhippetWatcher
> File "/Users/user/qwerty/project/project/myscript.py", line 3, in 
> from watchdog import Observer
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'

I have tried the answer on another thread with similar issue but it did not fix this: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'watchdog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60730383/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-watchdog)

Answer (score 1):

A colleague helped solved this but posting for reference:

I deactivated my python venv, pip uninstalled nose2, then activated the venv again and it worked.

I think the problem was a pip3 install of nose2 made it global so the venv was using that nose2 and not the environments nose2.